# Is there a way to set timeouts in tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, timeout

Can I set timeouts for JSP pages in tomcat either on a per page or server level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server level, you can try this.
you have to change `catalina.bat` / `catalina.sh` file

```
jvm OPTIONS : -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=60000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000
```

Answer (score 6):

In the Tomcat *server.xml* file, the Connector element also has a `connectionTimeout` attribute in milliseconds.

Example:

```
<Connector
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    disableUploadTimeout="true"
    enableLookups="false"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    maxSpareThreads="75"
    maxThreads="150"
    minSpareThreads="25"
    port="7777"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I have set connectionTimeout=5 and requests processing time is 50 ms but still I can't see timeouts